# Create a union or join on the values returned from groovy sql.rows()

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I am using Groovy's `sql.rows(SPCallString)` function to call a stored procedure which is returning some rows based on the arguments.

I am doing this for 3 different stored procedures.

Is there a way in groovy I can perform a "union" on those rows that are returned from the three calls?

I basically want something like this:

if these are the rows returned from `sql.rows` for each of the three calls,

```
->"X","Y", "M"
->"X","Y", "P"
->"X","Y", "Q"
```

I want to return

```
->"X","Y", "M,P,Q"
```

Thanks!

Comment: or do you want ["X","Y","M","P","Q"] - that's what I would understand as a union of the three.

Comment: This may be acceptable, though I am formatting this for a table that is fixed size, so if it was like this, i would eventually concatenate the M P Q columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it seems like you want to add all the rows returned by each proc to a collection, without any duplicates. If so, I suppose you could use a Set

```
Set<GroovyRowResult> rowResults = [] as Set
Sql sql = // instantiate using a Connection, DataSource, or whatever
List<String> spCallStrings = [] // add the SQL strings that calls each proc to this List

spCallStrings.each { spCallString ->

    rowResults.addAll(sql.rows(spCallString))
}
```